# Account report - Need to know how many accounts a sub team is selling to, not how many opportunities per account?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, account, custom-report-type

Basically I want to report on how many accounts are currently allocated to my sales teams not how many opportunities - So Sales guy 'James Bob' could have 50 opportunities all to 1 account I just want the report results to show as 1.

So the end results I can say Sales team A have 500 Opportunities to 200 Accounts.

Hope that makes sense and that you can help.

Kind Regards
Paul

Comment: see 'the power of one' https://www.ebsta.com/blog/2014/02/25/salesforce-hack-power-of-one/ and http://www.adminhero.com/power-of-one-the-most-brilliant-analytics-trick-of-all-time/

Comment: Awesome, add it as a comment and get the upvote and I can close this down if you wish? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an admin trick called "The Power of One" which has been around for years but is not obvious to even experienced report builders. Once I learned it, I automatically added the custom formula field `Account Count = 1` to all my orgs. Works with summary reports.  Reports on Opportunities can summarize the # of accounts, thus avoiding double counting an account present on more than one Opportunity

There are several documentation sources for this

- [Ebsta Blog](https://www.ebsta.com/blog/salesforce-hack-power-of-one/)
- [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMGW97jAoPQ)
- [Steve Molis (a SFDC MVP) blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/salesforce-tips-tricks-power-one-greatest-formula-ever-steve-molis)
- [The original posting](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tde) from ten years ago by Tom Tobin
- [Admin Hero blog](http://www.adminhero.com/power-of-one-the-most-brilliant-analytics-trick-of-all-time/)

Solution works for any report on children where you need to count only unique parents

Comment: This my friend is better than Christmas - I've been exporting matrix reports, filtering in excel and removing duplicates - Not too bad if it is one or two teams but i'm doing this for teams across the globes with over 6000 accounts!! Thank you so much